# Tuple as mapping key?

Tags: mapping

Can we use tuple as mapping keys? For example:

```
mapping ((address, uint256) => uint256) myMapping;
```

If not, what's the closest workaround? Consider the two components of the tuple can go up to `uint16`.

**EDIT**

To be more explicit, I can think of two workarounds. The first is a mapping of mapping, though I don't know if it will lead to any additional computational costs than knowing that the two mappings are always used together.

The second is a fixed 2D array (since it goes up to uint16 I can just allocate a 65536 * 65535 array. But this seems to have the potential of allowing a lot of empty spaces (especially if we consider that the value of the mapping might be a struct). I'm guessing such a huge structure might have larger transaction fees comparing to the sparse representation (especially at the beginning where the grid is almost empty).

**EDIT2**

Originally I was asking with the following example, which was misleading and made ppl think that this was my actual question. I have updated my example (above) to avoid the confusion. For this particular case below, a comment to my question cleverly pointed out that we can convert two `uint16` into one `uint32` and avoid the tuple situation.

```
mapping ((uint16, uint16) => uint256) myMapping;
```

Comment: Why not just put the two together into a single `uint32`? E.g. `(a, b)` to `(a << 16) + b`. (You can split them apart similarly.)

Comment: The two `uint16` is just an example, which happens to allow your workaround. But in general, as the title is asking, how do we deal with tuples. Note that the two component of a tuple might not share the same data type.

Comment: Let me change the `uint16` in my question to something else to avoid misleading readers.

Comment: `mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => uint256))` seems like the most natural thing to do.